# Angular: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.body.toggle')

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I have a problem with my angular Application. I get this error:

```
[Error] ERROR – TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.body.toggle')
```

In the Chrome Console this referred to the following HTML Part:

```
<mdb-accordion-item *ngFor="let item of menuitems" [ngClass]="{'no-collase': item.submenu.length == 0}">
                    <mdb-accordion-item-head mdbWavesEffect>
                        <fa-icon [icon]="item.icon" class="icon"></fa-icon> {{ 'webapp.menu.' + item.key | translate:lang }}
                    </mdb-accordion-item-head>
                    <mdb-accordion-item-body *ngIf="item.submenu.length != 0">
                            <ul>
                                <li *ngFor="let subitem of item.submenu"> 
                                    <a class="nav-link waves-light" mdbWavesEffect routerLink="{{subitem.routerlink}}">
                                        <fa-icon [icon]="subitem.icon" class="icon"></fa-icon>
                                        <span class="clearfix d-none d-sm-inline-block">{{ 'webapp.menu.' + subitem.key | translate:lang }}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </mdb-accordion-item-body>
                </mdb-accordion-item>
```

And my "menuitems" array looks like this:

```
menuitems:any[] = [
    {key: "dashboard", routerlink: "/settings", icon: this.faDashboard, submenu: []},
    {key: "settings", routerlink: "/settings", icon: this.faCog, submenu: []}
  ];
```

Maybe someone have an Idea an can help me.... I am using MDBootstrag for Angular in Pro Version.

Comment: where is the line of code throwing error?

Comment: It's the first on:

<mdb-accordion-item *ngFor="let item of menuitems" [ngClass]="{'no-collase': item.submenu.length == 0}">
                    <mdb-accordion-item-head mdbWavesEffect>

Comment: I think you misspelled "collapse", try : [ngClass]="{'no-collapse': item.submenu.length == 0}"